# How to display the number of icons/images based on number of rows in result?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm new to web-page designing. Learning PHP & HTML together.
I'm trying to display the number of icons dynamically based on SQL result.
I've a PHP code to query to DB and fetch the result. I've HTML code, which just displays the as many numbers i indicate (Static). I think I'm almost nearer to achieve it, but finding it difficult to integrate. Should i need to use AJAX for this ? How can i do it ?

**index.php**

```
 <?php
        $dbuser="root";
        $dbname="test";
        $dbpass="root";
        $dbserver="localhost";
        // Make a MySQL Connection
        $con = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
        // Create a Query
        $sql_query = "SELECT ID, UserName, Status FROM table";
        // Execute query
        $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
        $jsonArray = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $jsonArrayItem = array();
            $jsonArrayItem["ID"] = $row["ID"];
            $jsonArrayItem["UserName"] = $row["UserName"];
            $jsonArrayItem["Status"] = $row["Status"];
            array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
        //echo '<option value='. $row['id'] . '>'. $row['login'] . '</option>';
        }
        mysql_close($con);
        $tableData = array(
                "data" => $jsonArray
            );
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($tableData,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        die();
      ?>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>EXAMPLE</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
// AJAX uery.Call PHP and retrieve the result .Based on the number of rows, display the below elements
</script>

<div id="container">
    <a href="#">
        <figure>
            <button title="User1" class="   fa fa-user" style="font-size:100px;color:**green**"></button>
            <figcaption>User1</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <figure>
             <button title="User2" class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:100px;color:**red**"></button>
            <figcaption>User2</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
#container {
    text-align: center;
}
a, figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
figcaption {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bb3333;
}
figure {
    padding: 5px;
}
img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}
img {
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s;
}
</style>
```

If the Status is YES, icon should be in green colour. If NO, red colour. Could you please help me to integrate and achieve this.

Comment: You can just use `array_push($jsonArray, $row)` since the keys of `$jsonArrayItem` are the same as `$row`.

Comment: Where is your Javascript code that processes the AJAX response?

Comment: The code should loop over the returned array, appending the appropriate items to `#container`. You can give them a different class depending on the value of the `status` property, and then the CSS will assign colors based on the class.

Comment: @Barmar : I tried some snippet of AJAX to call PHP and get the result. But that didn't work out. Probably, you may help me here.

Comment: Is your script where you put the comment in the question? You can't have a script in the same `<script>` tag that has `src`, you need another `<script>code here</script>` tag.

Comment: Yeah, I had AJAX part where i've commented currently. How can i do it ?

Comment: Do what I said, put it in another `<script>` tag.

Comment: If you learned jQuery from a tutorial, it should have examples of the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't even need AJAX here. You can just get the result of the DB query and iterate over the array in index.php by foreach loop.

The point of using AJAX is to have let say a form in index.html and feed the DB with new entries and get the new info in index.html without reloading the page, which I don't see in your case. Or feed index.html with new data without reloading the page on some time intervals. If this is the case you can use jQuery.ajax() method. This method can be called by some event - button click or time interval. You can make a call like this:

```
$.get("index.php", function(result){
    var resultArray = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
});
```

Then you should use resultArray to iterate over and produce each individual user in .

Comment: I could able to do it without ajax, i mean iterating over for, while n if loops as per needs. But if there are more number of user details, all tries to fit in a same page which is not a good idea. How can pagination concept be included here (say only 10 user per page) ?

Comment: Query becomes: $sql_query = "SELECT ID, UserName, Status FROM table LIMIT {$perPage} OFFSET {$offset}"; $perPage = 10 or how many you want on page. $offset = (current page - 1) * $perPage. Offset for 1st page: (1 - 1) * 10 = 0; 2nd page: (2-1)*10 = 10. I hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks alot. I've implemented along with pagination feature as well.